# Web Usability: Save and Cancel ... or ... Cancel and Save?

Tags: usability

Windows and OS X have always bumped heads on this, but what is the general concensus on whether a Save button or Cancel button goes first in a web application?

[Save] [Cancel]

or

[Cancel] [Save]

Note: I have these buttons at the top of the form flush to the right.

Comment: This is very individual and argumentive

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50335/ok-cancel-or-cancel-ok

Comment: Are you supporting touch-screen devices? If so, most people are right-handed, so put the most-often-clicked button on the lower-right-hand-side, especially if it is safe to 'Save' but loses your work to 'Cancel'.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Follow the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment): do it the Windows way ([Save] [Cancel]) unless you have reason to believe that Mac users make up a greater portion of your user base.

Comment: This seems pretty unusual. Are there many Windows forms that have the Cancel button at the top-right?

Answer (score 18):

The key here is that we are talking ***"web"*** usability.  To that point, I think it is pretty clear that the [principal of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) referenced in the accepted answer would suggest that right is the forward action (save) and left is the backwards action (cancel), and not what the accepted answer suggests.

The web browser is the user interface web users are most accustomed to, and 15+ years of web browsing has made it pretty clear that the back button is to the left of the forward button.  It also jives with the left to right based languages that the web was initially developed for.  The right is where you are going, the left is where you have been.

Even in general computer vernacular, a forward slash, /, leans right while a back slash, \, leans left.

The windows UI is the outlier here, and I think it is a poor decision to base your UI design on Microsoft's precedence.

I might point out that your top right corner positioning of the two buttons is non-standard, but I don't think it bears on the ordering of the buttons themselves.

Answer (score 7):

Instinctively I always put the Save button as the rightmost element.

I think there are other things to consider. Primarily whether a Cancel button is actually needed, or whether another element (such as a breadcrumb trail pointing to the previous page) might be more appropriate.

Edit: http://www.lukew.com/resources/articles/web_forms.html - The section 'Primary and Secondary Actions' shows how visual weighting can be used to good effect as well.

Answer (score 4):

For all the heated arguments this issue can generate, it doesn’t seem to make much difference in actual human performance. The [advantages and disadvantages of each work out to a wash](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/ok-cancel.html). Users appear [equally likely to expect Cancel on either the left or right](http://measuringuserexperience.com/SubmitCancel/index.htm) in web forms. There appears to be a bias to favor Cancel on the left if the buttons are widely separated, but you don’t want to do that since [putting the Execute button the far right is associated with slow responses and high error rates](http://www.lukew.com/resources/articles/PSactions.asp) on web forms.

I’d say the most important thing is to be internally consistent in you app, and be sure Cancel is always labeled “Cancel” (not, say, “Return” like I saw in one web app). Otherwise, put the buttons next to each other and near the last field the user will look at (which is probably not in the upper right of the form).

And don’t worry about it too much.

Comment: I agree. Also, we should keep in mind responsive design. If primary button would be on the right side, then it might fall under cancel button on mobile devices. Which is totaly unintuitive, when You see cancel button and then primary button.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not a big difference either way, as long as it is clear what the buttons do.
My personal vote would be to have save on the left, as that is what people do the most often, and people read left-to-right.

Also, I would also put some space between the buttons, to make sure users don't accidently click one when they are trying to click the other.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a cancel button at all?

On a web form, the user can almost always cancel through some other action. Putting "Cancel" near "Save" is creating a situation where the user has a good chance of [firing the ejection seat](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/the-opposite-of-fitts-law.html) when all they want to do is save.

Comment: I disagree with the first part, but the second part is spot on.  I've thought about using larger buttons for commits than Cancels, but it just looks outright ugly.

Answer (score 1):

I generally put the button which will cause the most actions to occur farthest away from the center.  If your buttons are top-right, my order would be [Cancel][Save]

Answer (score 1):

Familiarity is often more important than being objectively correct, since things that are unfamiliar are often, by default, less usable.

People use their Windows PC or their Mac more than your app or website. So if I were in your shoes, I'd pick the order which you think will be familiar to the users you care most about.  If it's a mostly-mac audience, do it the mac way. If mostly PC audience, do it the PC way.

Comment: I guess one thing I could do is detect User Agent and for Safari users push it one way using CSS and another for non-Safari users though that may be volatile.

Comment: @Nissan, don't make it different in different browsers.  That would be very confusing for users who switch browsers.

Answer (score 1):

On a normal form, **Save should be under the form fields. Cancel should be to the left or right of Save, but not too close** to avoid tragic mistakes. Luke W's [Web Application Form Design page](http://www.lukew.com/resources/articles/web_forms.html) has some illuminating diagrams.

Your form is unusual in that you want the buttons to be at the top. In this case I'd need to know what the page looks like and how it will be used. But since you're already breaking any flow between form fields and Save, I suspect **Save should be on the right** to support the natural left-to-right path.

(Windows and Mac have differing standards for button placement *on dialog boxes*, and they both have the buttons at the bottom. These standards do not apply to web pages.)